# Show DIV when text is entered

Tags: jquery

I have tried everything to get this to work on ALL platforms. What am I doing wrong?

JS--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gname').keypress(function() {
       if ($(this).val() == "Toys") 
          $('#number').slideDown('fast')
       else 
          $('#number').hide();
    });
});
```

CSS--

```
#number { display: none; height: 100px; border: solid 1px #ddd; }
```

HTML--

```
Type here:<input type="text" id="gname">
<div id="number">
    Test 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind to the `keyup` event rather than `keypress` the value will have been changed by the time the event handler runs: http://jsfiddle.net/azHQz/

```
$(function(){
    $('#gname').on('keyup', function(event) {
        //if (event.keyCode == 13) {//un-comment this to only check the value when the enter key is pressed
            if ($(this).val() == "Toys")
                $('#number').slideDown('fast')
            else
                $('#number').hide();
        //}//un-comment this to only check the value when the enter key is pressed
    });
});
```

A demo for only checking the value when the enter key is pressed: http://jsfiddle.net/azHQz/1/

Comment: What if I wanted it to only to pop up after the on enter event no matter what they typed? Is that possible? I am lucky I found this site. Thanks for the quick responses guys and gals. Really appreciated.

Comment: @user1086253 You would check the `event` object to see if the `keyCode` property is set to `13` (which is the enter key): http://jsfiddle.net/azHQz/1/

Comment: Would the event object be in the script?

Comment: @user1086253 It is exposed in the event handler, all you have to do is reference it as a parameter when you declare your anonymouse function: $(<selector>).bind('keydown', function (event) {/*I can access the `event` variable now*/});`

Comment: Any chance of an example. I got what I needed already but was hoping before I close this question out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your script references jQuery functionality but does not include a jQuery library. Please include jQuery into your document to activate this functionality.

Place the following in the head of your document before the first use of `$`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include JQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CSS:

```
#number {
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('#gname').bind('keyup change',function(){
    if(this.value.length > 0){
        $('#number').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#number').hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pSLhN/

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to include jQuery (pretty sure you know this, and just left it out of the demo, but you need it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you should be checking on the keyup event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#gname').keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "Toys") 
         $('#number').slideDown('fast')
      else 
         $('#number').hide();
   });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

And your source doesn't actually show the div. The div starts invisible, and the js either slides it away or hides it, but doesn't make it visible.

PS whoever edited the original question made a mess of it I'm afraid. There's a lot missing now.

Edit: ah, I see that's corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is working perfectly, since you have given `display none` to your div id, so it works behind the scenes which you are unable to see. Remove the `display none` property and it should work

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cSGRu/3/)